Как заставить xtekky/gpt4free работать из под прокси?
Проект xtekky/gpt4free предоставляет возможность доступа к различным языковым моделям как посредству api, так и встроенного gui интерфейса. Все это можно запустить со своего компьютера, но тогда запросы к сайтам с моделями будут отправляться с моего российского ip, для которого вход на многие сайты закрыт.
Как можно запустить это все на своем компьютере чтобы он отправлял запросы используя выданный ему немецкий прокси?

Вроде как в README файле сказано.
